# Pulling remote master to a local repo cloned from a bundle

Tags: bash, git, zsh, git-clone, git-bundle

I have a local repo that I cloned from a bundle. I received the repo as a git bundle. After unbundling it and created my own branch, I noticed some bug on the code and notified the sender. They fixed the error and said I can pull the changes on the master branch.

When I switched to the master branch locally, I pulled and it says its 'Already Up to Date'. How do I know pull the remote changes from to a local repo I unbundled?

Comment: do you also have a url for that repository?

Comment: I do not, the whole bundle was emailed to me

Comment: ok, in that case, as indicated by ElpieKay in his answer, you should ask for an updated bundle or a link to a shared repository. Perhaps the other party said "pull from master" without thinking further, remind them that you only have a bundle and don't have access to an up to date repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Git bundle works as a read-only repository. The sender fixes the bug on their own repository. It seems you cannot directly access to their repository.

You have several options:

1. Ask them to send you another bundle which contains the new commits. And then you can pull from the new bundle by `git pull /path/to/new/bundle master`.
2. Ask them to send you the patches of the new commits. You can apply these patches by `git apply` or `git am`.
3. Ask them to create a transfer repository which both of you have access to. They push the new branch to the repository and you pull the updated branch from the repsoitory.